# Access the existing Delta lake table data in another Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, delta-lake

I am working with Azure Databricks and storing the data in delta lake tables. For some reason, I want to create a new databrick in the same network and access the existing delta lake tables from this newly created databrick.

I tried mounting to the same storage path and while running the query to `Create table if not exist` am getting the below error:

```
Error in SQL Statement: Analysis Exception: Cannot create table The associated location ('dbfs:/mnt/[REDACTED]/processed/leads') is not empty but it's not a Delta table
```

The location contains delta tables and files but not working with the new databricks.

When I try `Select * from table` it shows

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Table or view not found: leads_enrichment.leads;
'Project [*]
```

Most of the places it's showing to drop the tables / CREATE OR REPLACE, But I cannot lose the date in delta lake.

Can anyone suggest a way to access the existing delta table and data in the newly created databricks.

Answer (score 1):

When selecting from delta table(if the location is in storage mount path), use the below syntax.

```
%sql
select * from delta. `dbfs:/mnt/bricks3data/table1`;
```

[image]

> I tried mounting to the same storage path and while running the query

So, you stored your delta tables from one databricks to a Storage account and trying to access those delta tables from another databricks via mount path.

These are my delta tables stored in a Storage account from one databricks.

[image]

I have mounted this in another databricks and my mount point here is `bricks3data`. You can use the below code to store the delta tables in your new databricks.

```
%python
from delta.tables import *
for i in dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/bricks3data/"):
    table_path=i.path
    if(DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark,table_path)):
        table_name=table_path.split("/")[-2]
        print("Table_name : ",table_name)
        #Create delta table with same name from the mount path
        spark.sql("create table if not exists {name} as select * from delta. `{path}`".format(name=table_name,path=table_path))
        print(table_name," saved as delta table from storage")
```

[image]

**Tables stored:**

[image]

Comment: Try with use database_name before create table query.

Comment: Hi Rakesh Govindulal, Thank you this actually worked. I was able to create tables in my new data bricks with data. getting an error while specifying the database name in the query.    
   AnalysisException: Cannot create table ('`db`.`table`'). The associated location ('dbfs:/mnt/[REDACTED]/processed/table') is not empty but it's not a Delta table.                                                                 
   I tried below query  spark.sql("create table if not exists {db}.{name} as select * from delta. `{path}`".format(name=table_name,path=table_path,db=dbname))

Comment: Tried this: spark.sql("create database if not exists {db}".format(db=dbname))
                spark.sql("create table if not exists {db}.{name} as select * from delta. 
               `{path}`".format(name=table_name,path=table_path,db=dbname))     But getting the same error:-- Cannot create table ('`leads_enrichment`.`leads`'). The associated location ('dbfs:/mnt/[REDACTED]/processed/leads') is not empty but it's not a Delta table   I want to create delta tables under the same database with the same name. Sorry, am new to databricks.